# Need help adding columns to jTable

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.1, and can't figure out how to add columns to my jTable in the following method.

Here is the code:

```
private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
{                                               
 int length = 0;
 TableColumn [] colList = new TableColumn [length]; 
 try
    {
      length = getFileLength();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
      Logger.getLogger(list.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  tableAss.addColumn(colList[0]);        
}
```

I will get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Any ideas on what is going out of bounds? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's going out of bounds because `colList` has zero length.

Answer (score 1):

You could arrange your code like this to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
{          
    try {
       TableColumn[] colList = new TableColumn[getFileLength()];
       if(colList.length > 0) {
          tableAss.addColumn(colList[0]);  
       }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(list.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }     
}
```

However, it seems you are not filling `colList` in any place.